# remove selection after delete item angularitem

Tags: angular, angular8, ngrx

```js
  /**
   *
   * @param context
   * @param callBack
   */
  execute(context): Observable<any> {

            const codes = context.rowsIdList;
    return this.service.delete(codes);


  }

  postExecute(value): Observable<any> {
    this.message.show(`Selected items are deleted successfully`,`success`);
    return of(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: what are u trying to ask?

Comment: @ahlem, I've formatted your code, please add a few words explaining the question. Thank you.